# Limit with 2 parameter: $\,\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (1-A^\epsilon B^\epsilon)\frac{A-1}{A^\epsilon-1}$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to calculate the limit of this expression:

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (1-A^\epsilon B^\epsilon)\frac{A-1}{A^\epsilon-1}
$$

By replacing A and B with numerical values, I can see that the limit exists, but I have no idea how to calculate it formally.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite this limit as
$$
(A-1)\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1-(AB)^\varepsilon}{A^\varepsilon-1}
$$
which can be solved using Hôpital's rule: You obtain
$$
(A-1)\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{-(AB)^\varepsilon\ln(AB)}{A^\varepsilon\ln(A)}=(1-A)\frac{\ln(AB)}{\ln(A)},
$$
provided $A,B>0$.

EDIT: Missing sign inserted, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It seems you have lost a minus sign if I'm not wrong. Take a look also to my solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I personally didn't know about this rule! It seems that a minus sign is missing, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not a "2-variable limit" since the variable is $\epsilon$ while $A$ and $B$ can be defined as parameters.

That being said, we can proceed using the standard result $\frac{e^\varepsilon-1}\epsilon \to 1$, as follows

$$\frac{1-(AB)^\epsilon}{A^\varepsilon-1}=\frac{1-e^{\epsilon\log(AB)}}{e^{\epsilon\log(A)}-1}=$$
$$=\frac{1-e^{\epsilon\log(AB)}}{\epsilon\log(AB)}\;\frac{\epsilon\log(A)}{e^{\epsilon\log(A)}-1}\;\frac{\log(AB)}{\log(A)} \to -1\cdot 1\cdot \frac{\log(AB)}{\log(A)}=-\frac{\log(AB)}{\log(A)}$$

therefore

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (1-A^\epsilon B^\epsilon)\frac{A-1}{A^\epsilon-1}=(1-A)\frac{\log(AB)}{\log(A)}$$

for $A>0$ and $B>0$.

For the case $A=0$ we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (1-A^\epsilon B^\epsilon)\frac{A-1}{A^\epsilon-1}=-1$$

and the case $A\neq 0$ and $B=0$ we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (1-A^\epsilon B^\epsilon)\frac{A-1}{A^\epsilon-1}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{A-1}{A^\epsilon-1}$$

which leads to different side limits.